# the dll does not work in asp.net in IIS

Tags: asp.net, dll

I have an Asp.net application which require a third-part .dll from other department(In fact,it is one of the WebSerivce which need the .dll file).

I put the .dll file into the myapp/bin.

Then if I debug this application,it works,there is no error occur.

But once I run the application in normal model( I mean create a virtual dir pointing to my application path in the IIS),I always get the "**Service Unavailable**" page. And what's more,the app pool "**DefaultAppPool**" will be stoped.

I wonder why?

UPDATE:
error id:

> Message 1
>
> Source: W3SVC Event ID: 1011 A process serving application pool
>   'DefaultAppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the World
>   Wide Web Publishing Service. The process id was '5684'. The data field
>   contains the error number. Error number: 8007006d
>
> Message 2
>
> Source: W3SVC Event ID: 1002 Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is
>   being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the
>   process(es) serving that application pool.
>
> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885654/en-us

Comment: event log says what?  Also, what about the fusion log?

Comment: Either look in the event log or try setting "<customErrors mode="Off">" in the web.config and tell us what exception/message is shown. Without the message, we can not help.

Comment: Start | search for "Event Viewer" and run it ... then look in the Application Error log.  You may see some errors in there relating to the problem you're describing

Comment: Why do you think the error connecting to the dll? The problem is probably in your iis

Comment: first,I clear All the events,then I run my application,the same error occur,but the areon new events added.  However,In the httperr1.log,I found something :connection_abandoned_by_apppool....503 appoffline Defaultapppool.

Comment: why I think it's caused by the DLL is that my application work well before the DLL added,and it also work in the debug model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dll is unmanaged it needs to be explicitly registered to work within IIS7. Otherwise the appPool will just shut down.

[Register and Enable a Native Module on a Web server (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771133%28WS.10%29.aspx)

> You might have to register a native module if an application on your
>   Web server requires the behavior supported by the module. After you
>   register a native module, that module will be loaded and available in
>   every application pool on the server, but you must also enable it by
>   adding it to the list on the Modules feature page. For example, you
>   might have a custom authentication module that an application
>   requires. You must register the .dll file, and then enable the native
>   module to run. You can then enable the module at any level at which
>   the module is needed, such as at a site or an application level.

Comment: if so,How to Register the DLL explicitly?  I am using iis6

Comment: In IIS6 you shouldn't actually need to, it's only an issue with IIS7 (didn't know which you were using). One other thing to check - did you download the dll? In which case it might be blocked, right-click properties choose unblock.